# Is there anyway to build windmill like animation in CSS/JS?

Tags: css, animation

[Demo Pic Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDU5R.png)
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/SRachel/pen/wvrJjwZ?editors=1101)
I made four elements A~D and place them on location 1~4 using CSS `position: absolute`.
My goal is to make the elements move like a windmill on click, and emphasis the element on location 1, for example:

Example:

1. click on elementD (located on 4), D will move to 1 with 1.5x scale larger, at the same time, A will move to 2, B -> 3, C -> 4

Position now should be:
A@2 B@3 C@4 D@1(1.5x size)

2. then, click on B (which is in location 3 now), B will move either clockwise or anti-clockwise to location 1 with 1.5x scale
   other elements will move as well, D will resized to the original size.

---

I am new to frontend and I was asked to make this animation.. wish anyone can give me so direction to do it... Thank you!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990942/moving-a-div-along-a-circular-path-using-html-javascript-css

Comment: Have a look at transform rotate and see where you get to - rotating the whole thng (if it is to look like a windmill rather than the individual parts rotating). Then if you get stuck post your code in your question describing what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I made a pen here:
https://codepen.io/shahriarkh/pen/rNGwQMQ?editors=1100

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: skyblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.windmill {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;

  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: orbitAll;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
}

.wheel {
  background: transparent;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px; /* (180-80)÷2 */
  left: -50px;
  border: 8px solid #804040;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

/*  .axis {
   width: 8px;
   height: 180px;
   background: #804040;
   position: absolute;
   margin: auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
 } */

.blade {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background: brown;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 32px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: tahoma;

  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: orbitBlade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
}

#b1 {
  right: 80px;
}

#b2 {
  bottom: 80px;
}

#b3 {
  left: 80px;
}

#b4 {
  top: 80px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbitAll {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbitBlade {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="windmill">
    <div class="wheel">
      <!--       <div class="axis"></div>
      <div class="axis"></div>
      <div class="axis"></div>
      <div class="axis"></div>
      <div class="axis"></div>
      <div class="axis"></div>
      <div class="axis"></div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="blade" id="b1">1</div>
    <div class="blade" id="b2">2</div>
    <div class="blade" id="b3">3</div>
    <div class="blade" id="b4">4</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The only thing you need to do is control the `transform: rotate(...)` by javascript and bind eventListeners to boxes (`.blade`s)

I just added some "not pretty" additional styles. Feel free to remove them.